# How to add one List into another List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add one list into another but it is giving me error of **The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collection.Generic.List.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments**

My code is:

```
public ActionResult RegisteredEvent(string Cno)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            List<tblEvent> eventlist = new List<tblEvent>();
            List<RegisteredEvent> list = new List<RegisteredEvent>();
            var db = new clubDataContext();
            int[] eventIds = (from m in db.EventRegistrations where m.Cno == Cno select m.Event_Id).ToArray();
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var item in eventIds)
            {
                 list = (from m in db.tblEvents
                        where item.Equals(m.EventId)
                        select new RegisteredEvent()
                        {
                            id = m.EventId,
                            caption = m.Caption,
                            description = m.Description,
                            date = m.Date.ToString()
                        }).ToList();

                eventlist.AddRange(list); //Here I am getting error
            }
             ViewBag.eventDetail = eventlist;
            return PartialView("RegisteredEvent");
```

Comment: There must be another error which specifies what exactly is wrong with the argument

Comment: `eventlist` is of type `tblEvent`, your `list` is of type `RegisteredEvent` , you can't use AddRange on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply speaking, you can only concatenate lists of *the same type*.¹

- `eventlist` is a `List<tblEvent>`
- `list` is a `List<RegisteredEvent>`

---

¹ This is not entirely correct: Since IEnumerable is covariant, it is actually possible to add entries of a `List<S>` to a `List<T>`, if `S` is a subtype of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

The T in `List<T>` needs to have the same type or inherent from the same base type

```
List<RegisteredEvent> eventlist
List<RegisteredEvent> list
```

or

```
List<tblEvent> eventlist
List<tblEvent> list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IEnumerable.Select` as this (I don't know the structure of tblEvent, so adapt this at your code.

```
eventlist.AddRange(list.Select(x => new tblEvent{ id = x.id, caption = x.caption, ... }));
```

But the best way is to create directly a tblEvent

```
//the list sent to View             
eventlist = (from m in db.tblEvents
             where item.Equals(m.EventId)
             select new tblEvent() //here
             {
                 id = m.EventId,
                 caption = m.Caption,
                 description = m.Description,
                 date = m.Date.ToString()
             }).ToList();
```